# How to make create_ap logs go to /var/log/create_ap.log?

Tags: bash, permissions

I am using **create_ap** script to create an acces point from my desktop pc's wifi adapter.

```
sudo create_ap wlp3s0 eno1  'p455w0rD'
```

After a while I'd like to save logs which are outputed direcly to the terminal screen. Using

```
 >> /var/log/create_ap.log
```

But getting an error for that usage.

> bash: /var/log/create_ap.log: Permission denied

Here is all command:

```
sudo create_ap wlp3s0 eno1  'p455w0rD' >> /var/log/create_ap.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination of pipes and redirections aren't affected if the source part has sudo or not. It's like two different commands.

To solve that, you can encapsulate the whole command into an elevated shell:

```
sudo sh -c "create_ap wlp3s0 eno1 'p455w0rD' >> /var/log/create_ap.log"
```

Comment: Thnx! Work like a charm.